# "clean" rule not existing in Makefile, but make clean produces something anyway

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have a small issue with my build procedure on linux.

For whatever reason in my code if I issue a "make clean" Linux produces a file called "clean". The thing is that I don't have a "clean" section on the makefile of my project.

It looks like my make is picking up the wrong Makefile from somewhere and this might clash with the Makefile of my project.

Is there anyway to know which makefile is looked up?

Comment: It's hardly "Linux" that is producing the file, it's the make program or some program that gets started by make. Also, it's hard to help with this when you're not showing any code, i.e. not showing your Makefile.

Comment: What commands does make execute when you run `make clean`? What's in this file called clean? For example, is it an executable that's produced from `clean.c`?

Comment: @SteveJessop: You are great! I found out right now that there is a shell script file that is used as argument of my makefile! It was in front of my eyes and I didn't spot it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Use the `--debug` command line option to have the make program tell you more about what it's doing.
2. Try adding a `.PHONY` declaration of the `clean` target.

Comment: unfortunately the --debug option doesn't tell me WHICH makefile ( I am looking for its path ) is feeded to make utility.

Comment: From the `make` man page, "If no -f option is  present, make  will  look for the makefiles GNUmakefile, makefile, and Makefile, in that order."

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your makefiles. Install it then run `remake -x` or even `remake -x -d`. (The `remake` utility is a nearly compatible variant of GNU `make`).

In your case, the lack of a phony `clean` target makes the `make` utility creating an empty file named `clean`.